# how to use $.ajax

Tags: json, jquery

when I navigate to 
http://localhost:54763/Colorbox/Service.svc/GetCustomers, 
I get the json data displayed..

but this on the client side did not generate the json data I need.. why?

```
            $.ajax(
            {
                type: "POST",
                url: "../Service.svc/GetCustomers",
                dataType: "json",
                data: {},
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function (json) {
                    var output = json;
                    $('#MyTemplateOutput').html(output);
                    });
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you should try using the full url like so and edit this line:

```
url: "http://localhost:54763/Colorbox/Service.svc/GetCustomers",
```

try that and see if you get a response back.

Comment: also, when you push this out to a remote server, you should have it point to that url, you could easily set up a javascript object to carry this variable like so: `pathArray = window.location.pathname.split( '/' );
var host = 'http://+'pathArray[2];` so in your code you can just use this like so `url: host+"/Colorbox/Service.svc/GetCustomers"`

Comment: could you do an alert on the url, also could you check in firebug that the request is made to the appropriate url, then check the response tab.  it's possible you may have to set headers so that your success picks up the data correctly.

Comment: POST http://localhost:54763/Colorbox/Service.svc/GetCustomers 405 Method Not Allowed 10ms 
ResponseHeaders
Date Wed, 16 Nov 2011 21:36:17 GMT
X-AspNet-Version 4.0.30319
Connection Close
Content-Length 1565
Server ASP.NET Development Server/10.0.0.0
Allow GET
Content-Type text/html; charset=UTF-8
Cache-Control private
RequestHeaders
Content-Type application/json; charset=utf-8
Accept application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
X-Requested-With XMLHttpRequest

Comment: try changing your method to get, like so `type: "GET",` and see if that works :)

Comment: thank you so much Robert, you saved my week! it happened because the ajax type was set to "post" which should be "get" instead